# How to get installed apps on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

How can I get the details of all the installed apps on my iPhone device, and the details of all the applications which are running in background? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Jailbreak it. That's the only way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we can get the list of Installed  Application.

```
NSDictionary *cacheDict;

NSDictionary *user;

static NSString *const cacheFileName = @"com.apple.mobile.installation.plist";

NSString *relativeCachePath = [[@"Library" stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Caches"] stringByAppendingPathComponent: cacheFileName];

NSString *path = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"../.."] stringByAppendingPathComponent: relativeCachePath];

cacheDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: path];

user = [cacheDict objectForKey: @"User"];
```

user Dict will give us all the information about installed Application.

Comment: thanks Deep for your quick reply, i am just going to use this and than i will reply you soon

Comment: how do i get the particular app is running in background or not.

Comment: I don't know it working or not but i think you can use "System" key word for get the data from cacheDict in above code it will give us all the information about system's apps and try this let me know its working or not.

Comment: ion iOS8 the com.apple.mobile.installation.plist is deleted with what it's replaced please?